# How we can dynamically show Buttons inside Power App, to be equal to the related list items.. is this possible?

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

We have a SharePoint online communication site, and it contains these 3 custom lists:

- Master List
- Child-1 List which contain a lookup column to the Master list
- Child-2 List which contain a lookup column to the Master list.

Now we are trying to achieve the following:-

When the user select/click on a Master list's item inside the build-in list view >> to show the following screen, which have 3 main tabs; Master, Child-1 & Child-2 + Sub-tabs for the Child-1 & Child-2 (where the Master can have multiple Child-1 & multiple Child-2), as follow:

[image]

When you click on each tab the related list item/s should be shown (the master tab should show the original list item the user clicks on + the Child-1 & Child-2 tabs should show item/s based on the lookup field + the Child-1 & Child-2 will have sub tabs equal to the number of   child-1 or child-2 items related to the Master item).

I have these questions:-

1. is this type of interaction applicable in Power Apps? so when the user clicks on a list item in SharePoint to open the above interface?
2. Does Power App support dynamically showing/adding tabs/button equal to the Child-1 & Child-2 items? i know that in Power app i can add buttons.. but in my case i need to dynamically add the buttons (which will mimic the sub-tabs) equal to the number of child-1 items and Child-2 items which is related to the master record.. For example, if the Master record has 5 Child-1 items, then 5 buttons should be shown and clicking on the related Button should redirect the user to the related item inside SharePoint list...

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

- To show/hide a button, use its Visible property.
- To redirect between Power Apps screens use Navigate(Screen name) function.

So you need potentially create more than one screen. One screen per item type.